# How can I pass date to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a createAdmin.php form with this section:

```
<p>Date of Birth:&nbsp; <input maxlength="4" size="4" type = "text" name = "year" value = "" placeholder="YYYY" > -
                 &nbsp; <input maxlength="2" size="2" type = "text" name = "month" value = "" placeholder="MM" > -
                 &nbsp; <input maxlength="2" size="2" type = "text" name = "day" value = "" placeholder="DD" >
```

Caching those values:

```
$year = (int) $_POST['year'];
$month = (int) $_POST['month'];
$day = (int) $_POST['day'];
```

And finally passing to mySQL:

```
$formBirth = "{$year}{$month}{$day}";
$createAdmin = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO admins (username, hashed_pwd, power, email, name, birth) VALUES (
'{$username}', '{$password}', '{$power}', '{$email}', '{$realName}', STR_TO_DATE('$formBirth', '%Y%m%d'))");
```

This method apparently doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you just concat the variables and pass correct representation to mysql? In your case this would be $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day

Answer (score 1):

Try to take all these into a variable and use that

```
$date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
```

Comment: I used concatenation with - between dates. It worked - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `/` on this one:

```
$formBirth = $year."/".$month."/".$day;
```

Or:

```
$formBirth = "{$year}/{$month}/{$day}";
```

Or using `-`

```
$formBirth = $year."-".$month."-".$day;
```

Or:

```
$formBirth = "{$year}-{$month}-{$day}";
```

See [Demo](http://ideone.com/lgDG5z)

Answer (score 0):

```
$formBirth = "{$year}-{$month}-{$day}";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date of birth<input type="date"  name="date" />(html 5)
<?php
$formBirth = $_POST['date'];
$createAdmin = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO admins (username, hashed_pwd, power, email, name, birth) VALUES (
'{$username}', '{$password}', '{$power}', '{$email}', '{$realName}',{$formBirth})");

?>

OR use this
<?php 
$year =$_POST['year'];
$month =$_POST['month'];
$day =$_POST['day'];
$formBirth=$year."/".$month."/".$day;

?>
```